# wc -l returning 0 on a non-empty file

Tags: newline, wc

I downloaded a JSON file using Curl on my server from https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?api_key=[my_API_key]

([I have uploaded the file to TinyUpload if you want to play around with it.](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=31561607758006666926))

The downloaded file is 1.5MB and has a very large (and valid) JSON object. However, on the server when I run the command `wc -l` against the file, it returns 0. Running `wc -c` returns the correct byte count.

I opened the file in TextEdit and it looked fine. I did notice that `man wc` on my server (CentOS 5.5) and `man wc` on my Mac (Yosemite) seem to have different descriptions for what the `-l` flag does:

CentOS 5.5:

> print the newline counts

OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite

> The number of lines in each input file is written to the standard output.

Which manual is correct? Does `wc -l` count lines or new lines? If it does count lines and not new lines, is there ever a case when `wc -l` could return 0 even when there is a line in the file?

Is it also possible that Mark's comment regarding Windows based characters on [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289526/the-wc-l-command-shows-zero-lines-on-csv-file) is the correct diagnoses? I ran `cat -vet` against my file, but couldn't find `^M` using grep, and it's way too much text to manually search.

Comment: Why do you want to count the lines in a JSON file?

Comment: @Evert massive legacy script, traditionally used on CSVs, that I don't have the time to replace. Part of the script is to check if the file it is processing has no data. I'm going to change it from `wc -l` to `wc -c` probably, but just trying to cover all my basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manpage on OS X also says (first paragraph in the description):

> A line is defined as a string of characters delimited by a < newline> character.

So there is no contradiction between the two versions of the mangpages.

Since your file does not have a newline, `wc -l` correctly returns 0.

Comment: Why does every post I find about counting lines in a file have people use `wc -l` then? Every line in your file could have a newline after it, except the last one, and then `wc -l` would return a value off by one.

Comment: Because most files do end with a newline. `wc -l` is also often used in pipes, where this is generally no problem either.

Comment: See also one of the related links in the side bar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline?rq=1 , which tells you it's a POSIX definition for a line.

Comment: I guess the logical conclusion is: don't try and count lines in a JSON file. In fact, why would you want to do that? JSON files can be formatted in multiple ways with the content being the same, but with 0 or 100s of (new)lines in it.

Comment: Not sure what version of OSX you are on, Yosemite's description even explicitly calls out a newline character: `A line is defined as a string of characters delimited by a <newline> character`

Comment: Argh: fooled by Markdown. I had the < newline> string in my answer, but of course MD turns that into (invisible) HTML. Put in an extra space to prevent that (escaping the < with a \ doesn't appear to work).